# UnsatisfiableError: Conda Install Keras Fails

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I just had a new installation of Anaconda3 and, when I type `conda install keras`, I get this error:

```
(base) C:\Users\Tejas>conda install keras
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - keras -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed version is: 11.0
```

I have an external graphics card, a RTX 2080 Super. I would really appreciate it if you could guide me through the installing of this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
conda update --all
```

After running this, Keras should install successfully.

Comment: @TheBossProSniper let me know the result.

Comment: While updating i got some import errors from some files

Comment: ImportErrors  from python with a traceback

Comment: The import errors are because the libraries you’re implementing are not installed in the anaconda env (base). Use conda install to install them into the conda env.

Comment: @TheBossProSniper check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072464/anaconda-integration-with-cuda-9-0-shows-incompatible-package-error